# How can I use v-if inside template string?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, web-frontend

I want to use `v-if` inside the template strings in the below image code. will writing `v-if` inside template strings work ?

[image]

Comment: You should just do `v-if="isLeader"`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim thank you for your advice, checking that in 2 mins.

Comment: How are these 'template strings' being used? They'll only be able to use Vue template syntax if they're ultimately being used to create a Vue template. It's unclear why you'd be generating large sections of markup as a string in the context of a Vue application.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 1):

I used ternary operator in the below marked(in Red) way and it works,Thank you everyone for your advices though.

[image]

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.